# cmake + Ninja using all threads even if specified otherwise

Tags: cmake, ninja

When building a project generated by Ninja, all cores are being used even when explicitly telling cmake and ninja not to.
I've tried the following approaches:

- `export NINJAOPTS="-j 1"`
- `cmake --build . -- -j2`
- `cmake --build . -j2`
- `MAKEFLAGS=-j3 cmake --build .`
- Building the project as: `cmake .. -G Ninja -DCMAKE_JOB_POOLS:STRING=compile=2;link=2`

My ninja version is 1.10.0
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

`export CMAKE_BUILD_PARALLEL_LEVEL=#threads` is working for me.